# How i can change the separator lines so they will disappear after the populated cell in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I've set each cell of UITableView with a gradient background, however, the gradients are displayed in each row where there are information. So after the information is displayed, there are some white cell with a separator displayed at the bottom. How i can change the separator lines so they will disappear, or set them white, or make a white background after the populated cell? Thanks in advance.

-For example, you have 5 cells but only 3 cells has content inside.  So the iPhone will show gradient background and information on the top 3 cells while the bottom 2 are left with white background and nothing inside. Since I've set the separator black.  the bottom 2 cells would also have the black separator.  So how do you set the bottom two separators to white while maintaining the black separator for the top 3 cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in tableview u can change the separator style to none in interface builder or in code give it like this

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 2):

For separator u can use for example:

```
self.mytable.separatorColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
```

But i don't really understand what you try to achive in background color.

Comment: thanks, i've posted an example at the top. The code above can change every separators color. Is there any way you can change the color for specific separator or separators?

Answer (score 2):

Try one of these two:

```
tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Note that your cells would need to draw some separator on their own then.

Answer (score 1):

If You are using tableviewcontriller then use this line of code

```
self.tableView.separatorColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
```